# Confirm basis for $X \times Y$ topologies

Tags: general-topology

$X = \{a, b\}$ and $\tau = \{ \emptyset, \{a\}, X\}$

$Y = \{c, d, e\}$ and $\tau' = \{ \emptyset, \{d\}, \{e\}, \{d, e\}, Y\}$

Now, a basis for the topology of $X \times Y$ would be:

$\{\emptyset, \{(a, d)\}, \{(a, e)\}, \{(a, d), (a, e)\}, \{(a,c), (a,d), (a,e)\}, \{(a,d), (b,d)\}, \{ (a,e), (b,e) \}, \{(a,d), (a,e), (b,d), (b,e)\}, X \times Y \}$

I would love confirmation so that I understand I have a hang of it.

Comment: Basis for $X\times Y$ is $U\times V$ where $U\subset X, V\subset Y$ are basic open sets.  Right now, your $X\times Y$ has many more open sets than necessary.

Comment: @chriseur, I simply got every $U \times V$. Is that not a basis? I'm aware that I could get rid of things like $\{(a, d), (a,e)\}$ because it is the union of $\{(a,d)\}, \{(a,e)\}$, but is it not right?

Comment: Technically, what you have is okay because listing every open set is still a basis.  But you'd like to find a "smallest" basis if possible.

Comment: @chriseur would you recommend I figure out the sub-basis first and build a basis off that? I'm not completely strong with product topologies. Not sure how I would achieve that.

Comment: Note that $B=\{\{a\}, X\}$ and $C=\{\{d\}, \{e\}, Y\}$ are bases for $X$ and $Y$ (respectively). Now write all $U\times V$ where $U\in B$, $V\in C$

Comment: All would be $\{\{(a,d)\}, \{(a,e)\}, \{a\} \times Y, X \times \{d\}, X \times \{e\}, X \times Y \}$

Comment: I think that does it.  (Check that those can actually produce everything you listed above)

Answer (score 2):

The sets $A\times B$ with $A$ belonging to the topology on $X$ and  $B$ belonging to the topology on $Y$ form a basis of the producttopology on $X\times Y$. Check yourself. Also note that I speak of **a** basis, and not **the** basis. More bases are possible. The empty set for instance can be left out.